# get maximum power delivered to R load

Tags: thevenin

help me to get maximum power to R load  del[image]ivered

Comment: Do you remember how to find a maxima or minima using calculus?

Comment: yes i remember @SpehroPefhany

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a homework question so i'll give you a hint.

1. First find the thevenin equivalent circuit across the load. To find the thevenin resistance open all the current sources and short the voltage sources.
2. Then find the thevenin voltage at that load point and this is best done by applying the superposition principle and considering each of the sources separately.
3. The resulting thevenin equivalent circuit will be a thevenin voltage source in series with a thevenin resistance and your load resistance.

According to your maximum power transfer theorem you load resistance will equal your thevenin resistance. If your thevenin impedance was a complex quantity your load for maximum power transfer would be the complex conjugate.

After this you can calculate the maximum power accordingly, using the thevenin equivalent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it just a review for exam... i get R thevenin = 19 ohm but v thevenin i can't get it so can you help me please @Sada93

Comment: @Asmaa Your value for R is wrong. Follow Sada93's directions carefully. V happens to work out very easily in this case.

Comment: Show your work, lets see where you are going wrong.